# Magento: Making custom category attribute

Tags: magento

I am trying to add some custom attributes to my categories in Magento.

So Ive created my first ever module which would add a single custom attribute, by following the tutorial here: http://gauss-development.com/blog/tutorials/adding-custom-category-attributes-magento/

Everything seems to be working fine, the modules appears to be installed (I can see it in System > Advanced > Disable Modules Output).

But my custom attributes are not appearing. At all.

Ive been through the tutorial for the last 4 days. Over and over again. Following it as closely as possible, copy and pasting wherever possible. Other tutorials I have seem appear to be similar to this, I tried following them as well. All of these tutorials end up with the same results, no errors, nothing appears to be wrong, the modules appear to be loaded, but no sign of my new custom attributes appearing.

I feel I am missing something not mentioned in these tutorials, but I have no idea what.

Can anybody think of anything I could be doing wrong?

If you need to look at any code, please look at the tutorial mentioned above. Is there a piece of information, or instruction that tutorial is missing? Remember I have no other experience with creating modules, so I am following these to the letter. If they are assuming I would have a basic piece of information, this is probably where I am slipping up, but currently I have no way of knowing what I am missing.

Answer (score 2):

Please check if the attribute appears in your database, you can search in the database table **eav_attribute** in field **attribute_code** for the name of your attribute (as an example from my files below, it would be **cat_short_description**. If it not appears there in the Database then there is some error in your modul-setup.

The Code i used (file etc/config.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Andreabiedermann_Categoryattributes>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </Andreabiedermann_Categoryattributes>
</modules>

<global>
    <resources>
        <Categoryattributes_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Andreabiedermann_Categoryattributes</module>
                <class>Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup</class>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>default_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </Categoryattributes_setup>
    </resources>
</global>
</config>
```

and mysql4-install-0.0.1.php under sql/Categoryattributes_setup/

```
$this->startSetup();

$this->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'cat_short_description', array(
    'group'         => 'General Information',
    'input'         => 'textarea',
    'type'          => 'text',
    'label'         => 'Short Description',
    'backend'       => '',
    'visible'       => true,
    'required'      => false,
    'default'       => '',
    'visible_on_front' => true,
    'user_defined'  =>  true,
    'is_html_allowed_on_front' => true,
    'global'        => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
));

$this->endSetup();
```

Please Check that **group** is set to "General Information", if it is not it will not appear in your General Tab in the Category view.

Another error your could check is if the files have the right names. It should have the right version number in it.

Also, if there were an error in the past and you want to correct it you need to reinitialize the setup process for your module. To do so, please delete module-entry in the **core_resource** table, logout from backend and log back in. You need to do this every time you want the setup script to run again.

Answer (score 0):

Just check if you need reindexing done. Go to System->Configuration->Catalog->Frontend and make *Flat Catalog Category* to No and then check if your attribute shows up. If it does then you need to reindex and clear your cache.